# Is there a way to describe a react lifecycle methods in typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I sometimes have a React components which looks like this:

```
interface IExternalDataSource {
    fetch(): Promise<unknown>
    free(): void
}

function getSource(): IExternalDataSource {
    // some logic with side-effects
}

class Foo extends React.Component {
    private source: IExternalDataSource | null = null;

    componentDidMount(): void {
        this.source = getSource();
        this.source.fetch().then(
            (value) => this.setState({ /* ... */ })
        );
    }

    componentWillUnmount(): void {
        this.source.free();
    }

    // ...
}
```

The code above is broken from the point of view of TS: `TS2531: Object is possibly 'null'` in `componentWillUnmount()`.

But a React component cannot be unmounted before it is mounted. So in fact `this.source` will never be `null` in `componentWillUnmount()`.

Can I express this invariant in TS terms? I know I can just write `(this.source as IExternalDataSource)` but this is ugly.

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no way to express the state of an object in a method. The field types apply to all methods. You can only perform an extra redundant check, or use a not null assertion

```
componentWillUnmount(): void {
    this.source!.free();
}
```

Comment: Hmm, I've never met the assertion before. It is not very different from `as` (but shorter), do I get it right?

Comment: @shau-kote Yup the same idea as regular assertions just shorter. Strict null checks raise a lot false positives, this makes it easier to silence the compiler. It's the clasic case of you have more information than the compiler so you should let it know through an assertion.

Comment: Thank you. It's sad to know that there is no feature to express this knowledge in types, though.